# How to scroll powershell so that the prompt is at the top of the console

Tags: powershell

Operating powershell in Windows 10 for things like git, I often find that I don't want to work just from the bottom of my console, but want to "walk" down the window.

Using `Clear` is often very handy. However, sometimes I want to just scroll the current prompt to the top of my console without actually clearing it. I understand that I can use `Page Up|Down` to scroll the console, but this seems to be a club where what I want is a hammer.

Is there a way to tell powershell (6 or 7) to scroll my current prompt (minus a few lines if I have a multi-line prompt output) to the top of the console window without clearing?

Comment: What's your operating environment?  Are you talking about during script execution?  Or are you talking about if you have something emit to STDOUT and you scrolled up to view the output and how to get back to the prompt quickly?

Comment: Not talking about during execution. Between/before execution.

Comment: CTRL-C is what I use.

Comment: I may have found what I want in just using `ENTER` to execute a new call of prompt() after using `Page Down`. I'll hold off answering my own question in case someone else has a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you found what you need by doing pagedown and enter.

I can't think of anything else myself except you could put that into a function.

```
function Step(){
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{PGDN 5}{ENTER}")
}
```

Then anytime you want the prompt to be at the top, you can just call `Step`. I personally wouldn't want the noise in my own console log so perhaps there would be some other way to call it than directly (I don't know of one) so it does not clog up your output.

Comment: Try `[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{PGDN}{Up}{Down}")`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this two part blog series I wrote. It may be exactly what you want! https://tommymaynard.com/clear-host-without-clearing-the-host-2014/. There's a video at the bottom of the first post; see if it shows you what you're after!